# Button click event

Tags: c#

Does anyone knows how to count the number of times a button is being clicked in a day? is it doable? For example, if a button is being clicked 100 times for a day, the number of times would be saved inside the database.

Comment: Buttons are everywhere. Is it Web, WinForms, WPF application or other?

Comment: Yes, it is doable, Just send a request to your database to update the counter. Setup your table With ButtonID, ClickCount, and update the counter by one in each click. Try it yourself first, if you get stuck somewhere then come back here and ask.

Answer (score 2):

you need to do something like that

```
static int countclick = 0;  
protected void btnclick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    count++; 
    btnclick.Text=count.ToString();
    //Run update query..
}
```

After getting value run an update query to store click event in database  for furture use.

**Second way**

You may save it in View Sate as well like

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    ViewState["Count"] = 0;
}

protected void btnclick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ViewState["count"] = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["count"]) + 1;
    btnclick.Text = ViewState["count"].ToString();
}
```

Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
static int count = 0;  

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    { 
       count++; 
       Button1.Text=count.ToString();
    }
```

then store Button1.Text on database.

Comment: And what happens when you restart the program?

Comment: @MarkusMeskanen Given the nature of the question the OP asked, "database" is likely not any sort of database; an OP familiar with SQL Server / Oracle / MySQL / etc would not ask this question.

Comment: @Mr.Smith I don't think you can just expect it's not a database. It's fairly easy to just c/p the usage of MySQL without any knowledge at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table in the database with the columns: "Date" and "Click". When the user clicks the button, search for today's date in the "Date" column. If today's date exists increase the column "Click" with one. If today dont exists, insert a new row in the Table with the current date and puts "Click" to one